# How to capture IP address of server providing HTTP response

Tags: http, go, ip

Using Go's [default HTTP client](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/), I am unable to directly determine the IP address of the server that processed the request. For instance, when requesting `example.com`, what is the IP address that `example.com` resolved to at the time of the request?

```
import "net/http"

resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
```

The `resp` object contains the `resp.RemoteAddr` property, but as detailed below it is not utilized during client operations.

```
 // RemoteAddr allows HTTP servers and other software to record
 // the network address that sent the request, usually for
 // logging. This field is not filled in by ReadRequest and
 // has no defined format. The HTTP server in this package
 // sets RemoteAddr to an "IP:port" address before invoking a
 // handler.
 // This field is ignored by the HTTP client.
 RemoteAddr string
```

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish this? My initial thought would be to:

1. Initiate a DNS lookup to remote domain
2. Create new `http` transport using returned A/AAAA records
3. Make the request
4. Set the `RemoteAddr` property on the response object

Is there a better way?

---

UPDATED - to use @flimzy's suggestion. This method stores the remote IP:PORT into the `request.RemoteAddr` property. I've also added support for multiple redirects so that each subsequent request has its `RemoteAddr` populated.

```
request, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://www.google.com", nil)
client := &http.Client{
    Transport:&http.Transport{
        DialContext: func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            conn, err := net.Dial(network, addr)
            request.RemoteAddr = conn.RemoteAddr().String()
            return conn, err
        },
    },
    CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        request = req
        return nil
    },
}
resp, _ := client.Do(request)
```

Comment: At best you can get the IP address of *a* server that processed the response, at some point along the way. That could be a proxy, a load balancer, a WAF, a reverse proxy... what are you actually trying to *accomplish* here? Why do you need the IP?

Comment: @Adrian This last server in the response chain is fine. Creating an archive using the WARC standard has a metadata field for IP address. While there are warc writers for Golang, none of them (currently) support processing a response into WARC format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only way to accomplish this with the standard library is with a custom [http.Transport](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport) that records the remote IP address, for example in the `DialContext` function.

```
client := &http.Client{
    Transport: &http.Transport{
        DialContext: func(ctx context.Context, network, addr string) (net.Conn, error) {
            var d net.Dialer
            conn, err := d.DialContext(ctx, network, addr)
            fmt.Printf("Remote IP: %s\n", conn.RemoteAddr())
            return conn, err
        },
    },
}
resp, _ := client.Get("http://www.google.com")
```

Tying the connection IP to the response is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: What would be a good way to persist this in the response object?

Answer (score 2):

you also can build a request with trace:

```
request = request.WithContext(httptrace.WithClientTrace(request.Context(), &httptrace.ClientTrace{
        GotConn: func(connInfo httptrace.GotConnInfo) {
            fmt.Printf("target ip:%+v\n", connInfo.Conn.RemoteAddr().String())
        },
    }))
response, _:= client.Do(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

httptrace form https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httptrace/

```
req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, strings.NewReader(body))
    trace := &httptrace.ClientTrace{
        GotConn: func(connInfo httptrace.GotConnInfo) {
            fmt.Printf("Got Conn: %+v\n", connInfo)
        },
        DNSDone: func(dnsInfo httptrace.DNSDoneInfo) {
            fmt.Printf("DNS Info: %+v\n", dnsInfo)
        },
    }
req = req.WithContext(httptrace.WithClientTrace(req.Context(), trace))
```